# Fixed rhomboid clip-path on elements of unknown width?

Tags: css, clip-path

My design calls for informational ribbon consisting of several adjacent [rhomboid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhomboid) cells of unknown width.

My attempt comes close but misses the mark in an important way: since I don't know the width of the element ahead of time, I had to use proportional values for the [`polygon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

This way, rhomboids *of different widths will not meet at the same angle* (as demonstrated).

I didn't see a way of employing the typical pattern of using negative pixel values that would allow me to specify a length in pixels *for* the bottom-right *using the bottom right as an origin*. It seems that `polygon()` interprets all coordinates from a single origin in the upper-left?

So, what are my alternatives for allowing elements of different widths to meet cleanly, and all at the same angle?

```css
.stripe {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rhomboid {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.second {
  margin-left: -23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid">1234567890</div>
</div>
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid second">1234567890 1234</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case I would consier another easier way more support than `clip-path`. You can do this with simple gradient:

```css
.stripe {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rhomboid {
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, darkblue 49%,transparent 50.5%) right/20px 100%,
   linear-gradient(to top left, darkblue 49%,transparent 50.5%) left/20px 100%,
   linear-gradient(darkblue,darkblue) center/calc(100% - 40px) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.second {
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid">1234567890</div>
</div>
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid second">1234567890 1234</div>
</div>
```

By the way with `clip-path` you can rely on fixed value using `calc` in order to keep the angle always the same:

```css
.stripe {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rhomboid {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(20px 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 20px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
.second {
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid">1234567890</div>
</div>
<div class="stripe">
  <div class="rhomboid second">1234567890 1234</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's fantastic, I always tried to avoid `calc()` because it seemed "slow" but this is called very few times, so would be perfectly appropriate. Thank you for the linear gradient alternative!